# Can we have a dynamic string input with as a variable present on the terraform resource block?

Tags: variables, automation, environment-variables, terraform, devops

Scenario: to have multiple Kubernetes deployments I have a skeleton.tf file that could create an app as per requirement with minimum variable changes and in different namespaces and I do not want to provide a default name so that I will give the input everytime I do a *Terraform plan* and *apply*

like

```
resource "kubernetes_deployment" "${var.deployment-1}" {
...
...
namespace= var.namespace_1
...
}
```

how do I achieve this? Is this supported, because I face a syntax interpolation error,
or

```
Invalid string literal: Template sequences are not allowed in this string. To include a literal "$", double it (as "$$") to escape it.
```

or

```
Invalid character: This character is not used within the language.
```

or

```
Invalid block definition: Either a quoted string block label or an opening brace ("{") is expected here.
```

I have read about the terraform workspaces but then, it would be a tedious task to be able to get the resource name as a dynamic input. any help or workarounds to this is appreciated.

Comment: Please ask for details if you people have specific questions. TIA

Answer (score 1):

The name given in the second label of a `resource` block is used only within the current Terraform module, so there is no need for it to be dynamically customizable. If you don't have a specific name to use then you can use a generic name like `"main"`.

Because this is a Terraform-only name, Terraform will automatically deal with it appearing in possibly several different instances of your module, because the full address of a resource includes the address of the module that contains it. The whole result is therefore unique with in a Terraform configuration, and the resource's local name is unique within the module that declares it.

Comment: Thanks Martin, your help is appreciated, What is the advantage if I work it out with modules and subset of strings or define variables as objects?